# Creating dummy variables for last choice - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I've got this data frame:

```
ID  Date        X   choice
A   07/16/2019  .   123
A   07/17/2019  .   789
A   07/18/2019  .   0
A   07/19/2019  .   456
B   07/16/2019  .   0
B   07/16/2019  .   789
B   07/17/2019  .   0
B   07/18/2019  .   123
```

I want to create dummy variables that say whether specific alternative from set of alternatives (123, 456, 789) was the last choice.

Notes:

- It should be done for each ID separately.
- Value of 0 means there is
  no choice, so previous choice (before the 0 value) has to be filled.

Expected result:

```
ID  Date        X   choice  123_L   456_L   789_L
A   07/16/2019  .   123     0       0       0
A   07/17/2019  .   789     1       0       0
A   07/18/2019  .   0       0       0       1
A   07/19/2019  .   456     0       0       1
B   07/16/2019  .   0       0       0       0
B   07/16/2019  .   789     0       0       0
B   07/17/2019  .   0       0       0       1
B   07/18/2019  .   123     0       0       1
```

Comment: [try this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

Comment: Take a look at the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first processing `choice` for replace `0` to missing values and per groups `ID` first shift and then forward filling missing values:

```
s = (df['choice'].mask(df['choice'].eq(0))
                 .groupby(df['ID'])
                 .apply(lambda x: x.shift().ffill()))
```

Then use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) of `Series` s and add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for all possible rows from list or from original columns without `0` and rename columns with [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
#possible values in list
#vals = [123, 456, 789]

#extract all sorted values without 0
vals = df['choice'].unique()
vals = np.sort(vals[vals != 0])
df = (df.join(pd.get_dummies(s)
                .reindex(columns=vals, fill_value=0)
                .add_suffix('_L')))

print (df)
  ID        Date  X  choice  123_L  456_L  789_L
0  A  07/16/2019  .     123      0      0      0
1  A  07/17/2019  .     789      1      0      0
2  A  07/18/2019  .       0      0      0      1
3  A  07/19/2019  .     456      0      0      1
4  B  07/16/2019  .       0      0      0      0
5  B  07/16/2019  .     789      0      0      0
6  B  07/17/2019  .       0      0      0      1
7  B  07/18/2019  .     123      0      0      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `get_dummies`:

```
new_df = (pd.get_dummies(df.choice.where(df.choice.ne(0))
                           .groupby(df['ID']).ffill()
                           .fillna(0).astype(int))
            .groupby(df['ID'])
            .shift(fill_value=0)
            .add_suffix('_L')
         )

pd.concat((df, new_df), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  ID        Date  X  choice  0_L  123_L  456_L  789_L
0  A  07/16/2019  .     123    0      0      0      0
1  A  07/17/2019  .     789    0      1      0      0
2  A  07/18/2019  .       0    0      0      0      1
3  A  07/19/2019  .     456    0      0      0      1
4  B  07/16/2019  .       0    0      0      0      0
5  B  07/16/2019  .     789    1      0      0      0
6  B  07/17/2019  .       0    0      0      0      1
7  B  07/18/2019  .     123    0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Value of 0 means there is no choice, so previous choice (before the 0 value) has to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

steps
 - create a column which replaces 0 with last choice using `ffill`
 - using numpy broadcasting compare unique choices with shifted last choice to get the dummy data
 - create dataframe form dummy data and concat to df

**Edit**
 - corrected code not considering ids
 - also added row 5 to test it

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ls = [("A", "07/16/2019 ", 123),
("A", "07/17/2019 ", 789),
("A", "07/18/2019 ", 0),
("A", "07/19/2019 ", 456),
("B", "07/16/2019 ", 789),
("B", "07/18/2019 ", 123),
("B", "07/17/2019 ", 0),
("B", "07/18/2019 ", 123),]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=["id", "date", "choice"])

df = df.sort_values("id")
prev_choice = df["choice"].mask(df["choice"]==0, np.nan).ffill().shift()

prev_choice[df["id"]!=df["id"].shift()] = 0

unique_choices = np.delete(np.unique(df["choice"]), 0)

last_choice = np.zeros((len(df), len(unique_choices)))

last_choice = np.equal(unique_choices[np.newaxis,:], prev_choice                       
                       .values[:, np.newaxis])

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(last_choice, columns = [f"{choice}_L" for choice in unique_choices])

pd.concat([df, dummy_df], axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
    id  date    choice  123_L   456_L   789_L
0   A   07/16/2019  123 False   False   False
1   A   07/17/2019  789 True    False   False
2   A   07/18/2019  0   False   False   True
3   A   07/19/2019  456 False   False   True
4   B   07/16/2019  789 False   False   False
5   B   07/18/2019  123 False   False   True
6   B   07/17/2019  0   True    False   False
7   B   07/18/2019  123 True    False   False
```

Comment: Well, still doesn't work. When I'm applying this on my data, the first row of each ID got 0 in all dummy variables, but the second row (if there is no choice in the first row) got the last choice from the former ID. I'll edit the data here..